# Efficient way to search a SharePoint List

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint list with columns as below:

```
Columns: Title | Description | Categories

Column Type: Text | Note | Lookup
```

I have a list of categories selected by the user that I want to search against the above list's Categories column and I'm building a web part for this search functionality.

What is the best route for implementing the search? Is it good to use CAML in this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no other viable way than using CAML unless you need some specific full-text search capabilities. However, to filter a list by a given column's value, CAML is the obvious choice.

Comment: Well, I guess there's no other way.

Comment: It's a pain to generate all the "<Or>" clauses for CAML.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider LINQ 2 SharePoint too. It's a bit easier syntax than CAML if you're familiar with LINQ. The start up time to code your solution is initially a bit longer though but the moment you've created your entity classes through SPMetal I think it's easier to use LINQ than to create CAML queries (from a readability perspective LINQ wins easily over CAML).

More info on SPMetal: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798329.aspx

Comment: I know CAML supports pagination. Using the entities generated from SPMetal is easier and more friendly; however, does it support pagination? Skip method maybe?

Comment: Yes, Skip and Take would be the way to go then.

Answer (score 0):

You have atleast three options:

1. CAML (I understand that sometimes it is frustrating to create caml. I would suggest you to use 'U2U CAML Query Builder')
2. SPMetal
3. REST service

In your case CAML is the convenient and fastest option because other two methods eventually generated CAML at the back end. but i would suggest you to read other two options as well because they are useful in other situations.

Comment: Hi Rahil, Please help me with a question on list filter on a calculated column - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47134641/sharepoint-calculated-column-filter-shows-formula-instead-of-values